# What Java versions does Griffon support?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, griffon

I want to write a Swing application in `Griffon` but I am not sure what versions of Java I can support.

Comment: The only reason I asked this question was to create the griffon tag.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Griffon website, 1.5 or higher.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Installing+Griffon